# Why does js function not send data when It is changed to a for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

This function works when sending one array element over and over on a server.

```
var data = [];
var arrayLength = data.length;

data[0] = "500,400,399";
data[1] = "453,544,3333";
data[2] = "g44,tyt,rraa";
data[3] = "g45,343434,43333";

function sendWind() {
    console.log('Wind sent to user');
    io.emit('chat message', data[0]);
}
setInterval(sendWind, 3000);
```

But when I change it to a for loop to send all elements of the array it doesn't send anything.

```
function sendWind() {
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        console.log('Wind sent to user');
        io.emit('chat message', data[i]);
    }
}
setInterval(sendWind, 3000);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You check the array length right before the assignment of elements to your array. Switch the lines to this:

```
data[0] = "500,400,399";
data[1] = "453,544,3333";
data[2] = "g44,tyt,rraa";
data[3] = "g45,343434,43333";

var arrayLength = data.length;
```

Otherwise, `arrayLength` will be 0.

Answer (score 2):

```
var data = [];
var arrayLength = data.length;

data[0] = "500,400,399";
data[1] = "453,544,3333";
data[2] = "g44,tyt,rraa";
data[3] = "g45,343434,43333";
```

Let's understand what's going on:
 - you declare data (which is an Array of length 0)
 - you declare a var arrayLength which is equal to data.length = 0
 - you try to access data[i] where i start from 0 to arrayLength = 0

So what you need is declare arrayLength after data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3] or not decalre it and use data.length when you really need it:

```
function sendWind() {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        console.log('Wind sent to user');
        io.emit('chat message', data[i]);
    }
}
```